# How to find error ("Unexpected token") in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, syntax-error

I have been making great progress and all of the sudden everything broke. I'm getting the following error message in my browser:

```
./src/PokedexSelector.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (48:9)

  46 |   
  47 | 
> 48 |   export default PokedexSelector;
     |          ^
  49 |
```

This doesn't make any sense to me as I have tried changing many things in the code and looking for missing curly braces etc but cannot identify the source of trouble. Even when I change things, the error just jumps around. For example, if I remove the last line and refresh, I get this:

```
./src/PokedexSelector.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (46:0)

  44 |     )
  45 |   }
> 46 | 
     | ^
```

...doesn't make any sense to me.

Here is the whole file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { capitalize } from './HelperFunctions';

class PokedexSelector extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: "National", pokedexes: []};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.generatePokedexList = this.generatePokedexList.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  generatePokedexList() {
    const pokedexes = this.state.pokedexes;
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myJson => {
      let results = myJson["results"];
      results.forEach(function(pokedex) {
        let pokedexName = pokedex["name"];
        let pokedexLink = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/" + pokedexName;
        let pokedexDisplayName = capitalize(pokedexName.replace('-',' '));
        pokedexes.push(
          {
            name: pokedexName,
            "displayName": pokedexDisplayName,
            "link": pokedexLink
          }
        );
      });
    })
  }

  render() {
    this.generatePokedexList();
    return (
      <select id="pokedex-selector" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange()}>
        <option> {capitalize(this.state.value)} </option>
      </select>
    )
  }


  export default PokedexSelector;
```

Comment: Your curly braces are not balanced. Add another closing `}` after the render method to close out the class before the `export default` line.

Answer (score 2):

Add "}" after render. Class is still open.